# (block-matrices) tag is behaving strangely

Tags: support, tagging, tag-management

I'm not sure what's going on with the [block-matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/block-matrices) tag.  I recently tried to tag a question as block-matrix related through an edit, but when I did the tag didn't show up.

I can look up the (block-matrices) tag in the site's [tags tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags) to find that there are currently 172 questions with this tag, but clicking on the tag itself redirects me to the list of questions tagged with (matrices).  I tried to duplicate this event with defunct/burninated tags, but those don't show up in the search.

So what gives?  What's going on here?

Comment: Sounds like something was synonymized.

Comment: I removed the synonym so now this isn't like this anymore for this tag, but there are similar ones where it could still happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tag [block-matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/block-matrices) is a synonym of [matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrices). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/matrices/synonyms) for list of synonyms of matrices and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) is list of all tag synonyms.

In practice that means that if you add the tag [block-matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/block-matrices), it is automatically changed to [matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrices).

For more details see: [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

Comment: Aww. I was going to post this. But you beat me by a few seconds.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks, to both of you.

Comment: Is this the desired behavior? Do we actually want it to be synonymized? Where was the original discussion of this?

Comment: @NickAlger I do not recall such a discussion on meta and I was not able to find one. In the list of tag synonyms you can see that it was done not by a moderator but by voting of regular users. In fact, the users who proposed this particular synonym even [got synonymizer badge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/119/synonymizer?userid=56747) - so I assume that the date when the badge was awarded is the same as the date when the synonym was approved.

Comment: It is probably clear, but I will mention anyway that the question whether they should synonyms is different from the OPs questions. If there is need to discuss it, then it should be done elsewhere - either in the [designated thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22348/tag-management-2016) or as a separate question on meta.